# Was Ben Solo sent away twice?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, kylo-ren

That's what it seems. Leia remembers him as an angry teenager in The Last Jedi novel. He was around the house apparently.

Kylo (same book) remembers hearing Han and Leia arguing about him, and I think this was also his adolescent self.

But we also know that he was sent away when he was 11. That's in the Kylo Ren comic and alluded to in the Visual Dictionary.

Comment: Given how many times these films were re-written, it's astounding that there aren't more of these canon discontinuities.

Comment: The answer is Greedo sent Ben away first...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that as of 2023 canon, he started training with Luke when he was 9 years old. According to *Star Wars: Timelines*:

> **15 ABY: Luke the Teacher**
>
> Ben joins his uncle to be trained in the ways of the Force. As his first official Padawan, Leia's son poses a new challenge for Luke, who has learned from some of the greatest Jedi himself.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Timelines*, page 268</sub>

Ben was born in 5 ABY, so this would have happened the year he turned 10. *Skywalker: A Family at War* also says he was Luke's student before he was 10:

> As Ben neared the age of 10, he was Luke's most prized student. Even without training, it was clear that Ben was gifted in the ways of the Force, a Solo in name but a Skywalker by blood. Leia hoped that Luke's tutelage would keep her son from being tempted by the darkness. But without invitation, the child was visited by an insidious voice.
>
> <sub>*Skywalker: A Family at War*, Target edition, page 235</sub>

As for Leia and Ben's recollections, here are their flashbacks in the novelization of *The Last Jedi*:

> Ben in adolescence, his face grown lean above a strong jaw. A boy who always seemed alone, a churning storm in the Force. And whose anger had begun to manifest in malfunctions and breakdowns and objects that fell off shelves and shattered with no one near.
>
> [...]
>
> For a moment Kylo let himself recall his parents' worried conversations behind closed doors, the ones they'd deluded themselves into thinking he wouldn't know about. Conversations about the anger and resentment that had boiled over once again in their son. Conversations in which they talked about him like he wasn't their son, but some kind of monster.
>
> They were frightened of him, he realized. And so they got rid of him, sending him away to his uncle Luke—whose betrayal would prove far worse.
>
> <sub>*The Last Jedi: Expanded Edition*, page 100-101 of Kindle edition</sub>

I agree that it's a more naturalistic reading if these are both describing a time period in his teens, but they also don't explicitly say that they are, or that Ben never visited his parents after beginning his training.